# Transferring assets : Error code 4005 ASSET_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: wear-os

This is driving me crazy. I wrote a code quite a while ago that was working, and opened it again and it happens that I am not able to transfer my assets from the mobile to the wearable device.

```
public Bitmap loadBitmapFromAsset(Asset asset) {
    if (asset == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Asset must be non-null");
    }
    // convert asset into a file descriptor and block until it's ready
    Log.d(TAG, "api client" + mApiClient);
    DataApi.GetFdForAssetResult result = Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset(mApiClient, asset).await();
    if (result == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "getFdForAsset returned null");
        return null;
    }

    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "success");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus().getStatusCode() + ":" + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
    }

    InputStream assetInputStream = result.getInputStream();

    if (assetInputStream == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Requested an unknown Asset.");
        return null;
    }
    // decode the stream into a bitmap
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetInputStream);
}
```

And this is the code from which I call the loadBitmapFrom Asset method.

```
DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap();

ArrayList<DataMap> dataMaps = dataMap.getDataMapArrayList("dataMaps");

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> permalinks = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Asset> images = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < dataMaps.size() ; i++) {
   Log.d(TAG, dataMaps.get(i).getString("name"));
   names.add(dataMaps.get(i).getString("name"));
   permalinks.add(dataMaps.get(i).getString("permalink"));
   images.add(dataMaps.get(i).getAsset("image"));
}

editor.putInt("my_selection_size", names.size());
for (int i=0; i <names.size() ; i++) {
    editor.putString("my_selection_name_" + i, names.get(i));
    editor.putString("my_selection_permalink_" + i, permalinks.get(i));
    Log.d(TAG, "asset number " + i + " " + images.get(i));

    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromAsset(images.get(i));

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    editor.putString("my_selection_image_" + i, encoded);
}
```

And on the mobile side :

```
private void sendData(PutDataMapRequest dataMap) {

    PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
    request.setUrgent();

    com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mApiClient, request);
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
            com.orange.radio.horizon.tools.Log.d(TAG, "api client : " + mApiClient);
            if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                com.orange.radio.horizon.tools.Log.d(TAG, "message successfully sent");
            } else if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isInterrupted()) {
                com.orange.radio.horizon.tools.Log.e(TAG, "couldn't send data to watch (interrupted)");
            } else if (dataItemResult.getStatus().isCanceled()) {
                com.orange.radio.horizon.tools.Log.e(TAG, "couldn't send data to watch (canceled)");
            }
        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "Sending data to android wear");
}


class ConfigTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ArrayList<WatchData> mitems;
    int mType;

    public ConfigTask(ArrayList<WatchData> items, int type)
    {
        mitems = items;
        mType = type;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... str)
    {
        DataMap dataMap;
        ArrayList<DataMap> dataMaps = new ArrayList<>();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < mitems.size() ; i++) {
            dataMap = new DataMap();
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(mitems.get(i).mUrlSmallLogo);
                Log.d(TAG, "url : " + url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Asset asset = createAssetFromBitmap(bitmap);
            dataMap.putAsset("image", asset);
            dataMap.putString("name", mitems.get(i).mName);
            dataMap.putString("permalink", mitems.get(i).mPermalink);
            dataMaps.add(dataMap);
        }
        PutDataMapRequest request = null;
        switch (mType) {
            case 0 :
                request = PutDataMapRequest.create(SELECTION_PATH);
                break;
            case 1 :
                request = PutDataMapRequest.create(RADIOS_PATH);
                break;
            case 2 :
                request = PutDataMapRequest.create(PODCASTS_PATH);
                break;
        }
        request.getDataMap().putDataMapArrayList("dataMaps", dataMaps);
        request.getDataMap().putString("", "" + System.currentTimeMillis()); //random data to refresh

        Log.d(TAG, "last bitmap : " + bitmap);
        Log.d(TAG, "===============================SENDING THE DATAMAP ARRAYLIST==================================");
        sendData(request);

        return "h";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String name)
    {

    }
}
```

When executing that code, I see the following error happening :

```
02-02 14:47:59.586    7585-7601/? D/WearMessageListenerService﹕ 4005:ASSET_UNAVAILABLE
```

I saw that related thread [Why does Wearable.DataApi.getFdForAsset produce a result with status 4005 (Asset Unavailable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227254/why-does-wearable-dataapi-getfdforasset-produce-a-result-with-status-4005-asset) but it didn't really help me

Comment: Please show the code that calls loadBitmapFromAsset() as well.

Comment: Edited the code, but just before stopping my work, it suddenly worked, without making ANY change to my code... I just can't understand where it came from

Comment: You may be seeing the effect of a recent change that was made in Play Services to batch up data items and then do a data sync which can delay the sync up to 20 minutes or so (to preserve the battery for non-urgent tasks); there is an option to flag the PutDataRequest or PutDataMapRequest as urgent, in which case sync happens outside of that scheduled process.

Comment: Aw okay thanks a lot! I'll try to set that flag tomorrow then

Comment: But please set that flag only if you really need the asset to be transferred immediately; for example if one is updating a contact's image, it doesn't need to be immediate and user's battery is definitely more important.

Comment: After updating the play services to 8.4.0, I still have the same problem after setting the setUrgent() flag when sending the data : error : Requested an unknown Asset.

Comment: I don't have access to your code to see how things are set up, it is not clear whether you are getting that error for all assets or just some. You might want to put more relevant pieces (e.g. how you are creating assets in the first place and sending them) so maybe something there is not quite right.

Comment: I added the code that where I create the request and I send it.

Comment: One thing which doesn't seem right (might not be the issue here but can't be sure) is that you make a number of calls that may throw exception and all you do is printing a stack trace and then continuing. For example, when you are getting the image urls, if an exception is thrown, you keep going; if creation of bitmaps fail, you still keep going which means what you are putting in the asset may not really be what you expect it to be. So please refactor your code so that an attempt to create an asset happens only if all the things it depends on have completed successfully.

Comment: You are right, I am going to change that for a proper error handling, however, nothing in the logs shows me that there is a problem there, so I must be correctly transferring the assets

Comment: update : I created a new project and tried to transfer an image, using the same code that I wrote on the other app. It works fine. May it be a dependency problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem... I solved it by updating the Google play service, and adding the same signing configuration to both the app and the wearable module. If it doesn't work on the first build go to "invalidate caches / restart" in files and it should work.